# MySQL self join referencing another table

Tags: mysql, join, self

I'm trying to create what I think is a self join, but I can't get it to return what I want.  I either get an empty set or an error about a non-unique table

I've tried to simply the query and just return the 'To Tag' and 'From Tag' but I always get a non unique table error

```
    select a.from_tag as 'From Tag', b.to_tag as 'To Tag'  
    from termination_schedule a
    inner join termination_schedule b 
    on terminal_associations.term_assoc_id=b.from_id
    inner join termination_schedule a 
    on terminal_associations.term_assoc_id=a.from_id;
```

The two tables I am trying to join are:
Terminal associations:

```
    +---------------+----------+----------------+----------+
    | term_assoc_id | tag      | terminal_strip | terminal |
    +---------------+----------+----------------+----------+
    |             1 | BC122EE1 | XP             | L1       |
    |             2 | BC122EE1 | XP             | L2       |
    |             3 | BC122EE1 | XP             | L3       |
    |             4 | BC122HS1 | 1              | L1-1     |
    |            10 | BC122HS1 | 1              | L1-2     |
    |             5 | BC122HS1 | 1              | L2-1     |
    |            11 | BC122HS1 | 1              | L2-2     |
    |             6 | BC122HS1 | 1              | L3-1     |
    |            12 | BC122HS1 | 1              | L3-2     |
    |             7 | BC122M1  | 1              | L1       |
    |             8 | BC122M1  | 1              | L2       |
    |             9 | BC122M1  | 1              | L3       |
    +---------------+----------+----------------+----------+
```

and
Termination Schedule

`````
| cable_no | from_id | to_id | core_mark |
+----------+---------+-------+-----------+
| 1001     |       1 |     4 | red       |
| 1001     |       2 |     5 | white     |
| 1001     |       3 |     6 | blue      |
| 1002     |      10 |     7 | red       |
| 1002     |      11 |     8 | white     |
| 1002     |      12 |     9 | blue      |
+----------+---------+-------+-----------+````

What I want to return is:
+----------+----------+-----------+----------+
| cable_no | From Tag | core_mark | To Tag   |
+----------+----------+-----------+----------+
| 1001     | BC122EE1 | red       | BC122HS1 |
| 1001     | BC122EE1 | white     | BC122HS1 |
| 1001     | BC122EE1 | blue      | BC122HS1 |
| 1002     | BC122HS1 | red       | BC122M1 |
| 1002     | BC122HS1 | white     | BC122M1 |
| 1002     | BC122HS1 | blue      | BC122M1 |
+----------+----------+-----------+----------+
`````

Comment: You've posted the table data for one table twice and omitted the other one.

Comment: You aren't invoking terminal_associations at all.

Comment: Thanks, I've just corrected it

Comment: You use the same alias `a` twice. Use another.

Comment: And qualify all the columns properly with table aliases.

Comment: At some point you should be searching for to_id in terminal_associations AND you should drive from schedule.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I got it working

`````
select termination_schedule.cable_no, a.term_assoc_id as 'From Tag', termination_schedule.core_mark,b.term_assoc_id as 'To Tag'
FROM termination_schedule
LEFT JOIN terminal_associations a ON termination_schedule.from_id=a.term_assoc_id
LEFT JOIN terminal_associations b ON termination_schedule.to_id=b.term_assoc_id;````
`````